# squid web proxy time quota database

Tags: squid, web-proxy

the doc about Squid time quota write: "*Filename   of   persistent   database. This defaults to ext_time_quota.db..."*. But how create time-quota.db? 
Squid is installed up and running, but ext_time_quota_acl doesn't found time_quota.db file and crashed!
Many thanks.

Comment: Did you add a configuration file? Making the config directory writeable by the squid user is not a great idea - for a new install I would be creating a zero-length file and setting the write permissions there first (although I don't know if that works). What is the exact text of the error message? What config ACL did you add?

Comment: Hi, yes squid is up and running with LDAP auth, and it is working fine. But now I need configure a time quota for every user, so I add this line in config file:  #external_acl_type time_quota ttl=60 children-max=1 %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_time_quota_acl /etc/squid/time_quota
#acl noquota src all
#acl time_quota external time_quota
#deny_info ERR_ACL_TIME_QUOTA_EXCEEDED noquota
#http_access deny !time_quota noquota

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem are the perm. Simply set chown squid:squid.